# Hover with checkbox hack

Tags: html, css, checkbox, hover

I'm trying to make a box whereby when the button is pressed the text is only shown "Reserved" as of right now it shows "Free Space!Reserved" as I have used the :after function. Is there any way to create a hover function so that it shows "Click here to reserve" when the box is green and hover "Mine" whilst the box is red?

The code is on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nayshal/s15dd8tu/1/) and below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="btnControl"/>
<label class="mouseover1" for="btnControl">Free Space</label>

.mouseover1 {

background-color: green;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5% ;
text-align: center;
width: 20%;
}

#btnControl {
 display: none;
}

.mouseover1:active {
margin-left: 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
outline: 1px solid black;
}

.mouseover1:hover {
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3e3fa, #a5defb);
color:black;
}

#btnControl:checked + label:after {
content: 'Reserved!';
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .mouseover1 {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Where would the hover text display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did use `:before` to show/hide the original text.

[**single button jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/89u5q8mh/1/)

[**multiple buttons jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ghdbc704/)

```css
body {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100vh;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

label {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
}

.mouseover1 {    
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5% ;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
}

#btnControl {
    display: none;
}

.mouseover1:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
    outline: 2px solid darkred;
}

.mouseover1:hover {
    background: yellowgreen;
    color: white;
}

#btnControl:checked + label:after {
    content: 'Reserved';
}

#btnControl + label:before {
    content: 'Free Space';
}

#btnControl:checked + label:before {
    content: '';
}

#btnControl:checked:hover + label:after {
    content: 'Mine!';
}

#btnControl:hover + label:before {
    content: 'Click here!';
}

#btnControl:checked:hover + label:before {
    content: '';
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .mouseover1 {
 background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btnControl"/>
<label class="mouseover1" for="btnControl"></label>
```

Comment: You genius! My god thats amazing thank you! Is there a way to make multiple ones so that a user can only click on one?

Comment: [**multiple buttons jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ghdbc704/) - I havesubstituted the '#btnControl css target' for the '.Control css target'. Plus changed the `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .mouseover1` (wich reaches all objects after it) selector for `input[type=checkbox]:checked + .mouseover1` (wich reaches only the next object). Of course the Ids and label targets were also modified since they must be unique.

Comment: Ahh thanks thats what I managed to do but couldnt figure out how to only select one of the buttons?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get what you mean. Can you use an example to clarify please?

Comment: As in once one of them are clicked the other cannot be clicked as one button is already selected

Comment: You mean the user cant reserve more than 1 slot? So use radio input instead of checkbox input.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nayshal/ghdbc704/1/ ahh like this? still doesn't select one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105273/discussion-between-nayshal-kerai-and-freestock-tk).

Comment: I'm using a mobile modem on a laptop its failing to connect on chat. [**check this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z7asmmc7/)

Comment: I'm waiting for your feedback about [**this last radio fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z7asmmc7/), is it what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I wanted. Just need to figure out on my website to link it to each account for selection with phpMyAdmin :(

Answer (score 1):

To change the text within the label, first wrap it in a div

```
<input type="checkbox" id="btnControl"/>
<div class="container">
  <label class="mouseover1 new-label" for="btnControl"><Span>Free Space</Span></label>
</div>
```

Make sure to add the "new-label" to the label class
Then change the CSS as follows:

```
.mouseover1 {

    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5% ;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
}

#btnControl {
    display: none;
}

.mouseover1:active {
    margin-left: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.mouseover1:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3e3fa, #a5defb);
    color:black;
}

#btnControl:checked + label:after {
    content: 'Reserved!';
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .mouseover1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.container:hover .new-label span{
    display: none;
}
.container:hover .new-label:after{
    content: 'Click Here To Reserve';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add span for the text and add class.

CSS

```
#btnControl:checked + .mouseover1 span {
  display: none;
}
```

Here you go: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s15dd8tu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use font-size:

```css
.mouseover1 {
    
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5% ;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
}

#btnControl {
    display: none;
}

.mouseover1:active {
    margin-left: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.mouseover1:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3e3fa, #a5defb);
    color:black;
}
#btnControl:checked + label {
    font-size:0;
}
#btnControl:checked + label:after {
    content: 'Reserved!';
    font-size:1rem;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .mouseover1 {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btnControl"/>
<label class="mouseover1" for="btnControl">Free Space</label>
```

or float and text-indent

```css
    .mouseover1 {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5%;
      text-align: center;
      width: 20%;
    }
    #btnControl {
      display: none;
    }
    .mouseover1:active {
      margin-left: 2px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
      outline: 1px solid black;
    }
    .mouseover1:hover {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3e3fa, #a5defb);
      color: black;
    }
    #btnControl:checked + label {
      text-indent: -999px;
      ;
    }
    #btnControl:checked + label:after {
      content: 'Reserved!';
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      text-indent: 0;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .mouseover1 {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btnControl" />
<label class="mouseover1" for="btnControl">Free Space</label>
```

or whatever else method you think relevant. best would be javascript to change text.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the text in a `span` would allow you to hide it easily. The hover text ("Click here to reserve / Mine") could be added with another pseudo element

```css
.mouseover1 {
    
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5% ;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
}

#btnControl {
    display: none;
}

.mouseover1:active {
    margin-left: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.mouseover1:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3e3fa, #a5defb);
    color:black;
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

#btnControl:checked + label:after {
    content: 'Reserved!';
}

#btnControl:checked + label span {
  display: none;
}

#btnControl + label:before {
    content: 'Click here to reserve';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

#btnControl + label:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}

#btnControl:checked + label:before {
    content: 'Mine!';
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .mouseover1 {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btnControl"/>
<label class="mouseover1" for="btnControl"><span>Free Space</span></label>
```